# sharepoint rest api GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl, result 404, not found

Tags: list, sharepoint, directory

i'm trying to list a sharepoint folder since some weeks. I've tried all what i've found.

Mostyl all examples uses site_url but nowhere is exactly defined how to build this site_url.

I can List the folder in the browser with https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/Freigegebene%20Dokumente

Now i've tried

```
private $hServer = 'https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions';
1: private $folderUrl = 'Freigegebene Dokumente';
2: private $folderUrl = '/Freigegebene Dokumente';
3: private $folderUrl = '/Shared Documents';
4: private $folderUrl = 'Shared Documents';
5: private $folderUrl = '/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/Freigegebene Dokumente';
6: private $folderUrl = 'sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/Freigegebene Dokumente';
```

and a lot more

then i call with laravel (guzzle http)

```
$url = "$this->hServer/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('$this->folderUrl')/files";
$response = Http::withHeaders([
        ])->get($url, [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer " . Session::get('sharepoint_auth_code'),
            'Accept' => 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        ]);

dd($response->getStatusCode(), $response->getBody(), $response);
```

Of course before that i call the login. If i change something in the login or Authorization part above i get Forbidden instead of not found, so i think this part is okay.

But i never get a valid result.
I'm running out of ideas. Is there any Tipp, what is wrong?
Many thanks and best regards

List Folder Contents from Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Hm have you tried to use the URL from the browser? I mean, this:

`/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/Freigegebene%20Dokumente`

Comment: yes, sorry.. :/

Comment: I would try to put the full URL you are trying to call with API in the browser address line. You can put API urls there as well. Maybe it be some encoding issue? The server relative URL is relative to the server root. The correct URL should be literally this: `https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/TeamraumWorkplaceSolutions/Freigegebene%20Dokumente')/files`

Comment: If i put the full url to the Browser i get an result (files.atom) with xml entries. Trying again with my code i get again 404. I have absolute no idea what to try else. Any more Tipps? I'm desperate :/